# Can i use stack panel to design the following layout

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am wondering If I can use stack panel to get the following layout

[image]

Comment: you can use, if you have any problem then share us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one will not be enough, but you can certainly do with two:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

    <BigBoxOnTop />

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <SmallBox_1 />
        <SmallBox_2 />
        <SmallBox_3 />
        ....
    </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

use margin and padding to place your boxes inside the panels

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The outer one looks like a vertical stackpanel. The smaller boxes (controls or panels) can be placed with explicit margins to lay them out as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to nest a gridpanel inside each of the vertical stack panel's top and bottom halves... but I'm just a beginner at WPF.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" Margin="5" StrokeThickness="2"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="35" StrokeThickness="5" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Width="100" Height="35" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="35" Margin="25,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```